# Unable to set margins to 0 in angular5

Tags: html, css, angular

With my app, I currently have only 1 component (the nav) and I have set the CSS for app-root, as well as app-navbar as:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Despite this, the margins persist; I can't even edit them in chrome web development tools in the browser for some reason, The only way I get the margins to disappear is to go the angular root index.html file, and manually enter the style tags there,

Anything else I apply to the `*` tag (such as font-family) is applied to the entire document, just not margin for some reason,

If anyone knows why you'd save me from ripping any more hair out.

Comment: Did you create your project with the Angular CLI ?

Comment: Well most likely a more specific rule targets the elements in question, and specifies different margins ...

Comment: @trichetriche, yes, I used the cli.

Comment: Ok then see my upcoming answer

Comment: @CBroe, there are no other styles specified by the browser. The margin is specified by user agent stylesheet, but I can't find the source of the rule

Comment: The Styles on Angular are scope that means they are related to their own component. But you can break it https://alligator.io/angular/viewencapsulation/

Answer (score 3):

You can add it in app.coponent.css

```
* {
   margin: 0;
}
```

and set encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.None` in component decorator.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

> By setting `ViewEncapsulation` to **None** all the styles apply to the entire document. Or in other words, a component could overwrite styles from another component because its styles are applied to the document head later. Otherwise you can use the global style.css file generated in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project with the Angular CLI, the CLI creates a global style file, usually under the name `style.ext`, where ext is the extension you chose (default to `css`).

So you should open this default file, let's assume it being `style.css`, and add those lines in it.

```
* {
   margin: 0;
}
```

If I were you, I would also add this to this file :

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will prevent you from some errors you could encounter later on, if you want to play with heights (I do this in all of my projects)